# How can one turn regular quotes (i.e. ', ") into LaTeX/TeX quotes (i.e. `', ``'')

Tags: regex, latex, quotes

Given a document written with normal quotes, e.g.

```
Ben said "buttons, dear sir".
I replied "Did you say 'buttons'?" to him.
```

What ways can one turn these sort of things into LaTeX quotes, with the appropriate semantics. i.e.

```
Ben said ``buttons, dear sir''.
I replied ``Did you say `buttons'?'' to him.
```

So that LaTeX produces:

```
Ben said “buttons, dear sir”.
I replied “Did you say ‘buttons’?”
```

My first thought is to turn to a regex. However, I'm not getting any hits from Google or the regex libraries for "LaTeX quotes regular expression", and of course "TeX quotes regular expression" seems to return too many.

Thank you.

Comment: regexes are not the right tool for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, this problem is harder than it looks.

The simplest cases *can* be treated with regular expressions, but for more general situations you will almost certainly need to build a recursive parser: regular expression will only work if there is no nesting.

The big problem is going to be associated with identifying single `"'"`s that are not paired---as is contractions (the `"'"` in `"don't"` should not be changed, *and* should not be paired).

---

Lets see if we can write a usable EBNF description:

```
input:       text+
text:        uquote|squote|dquote
squote       "'" text "'"
dquote       """ text """
uquote:      [contraction|.]+
contraction: [A-Za-z]+ "'" [A-Za-z]+
```

which is limited to contractions that have the `"'"` in the middle of the word. All the associated action will just echo the input, except that the `squote` and `dquote` terms replace the quotes as appropriate.

---

I used regular expressions followed by human fix-ups for a fairly simple one-off, but that would be labor intensive for on-going work.

Comment: Besides, one can add that in editors like emacs, when you type a `"` it uses `Tex-insert-quote` to remember if your quotes are opened (no nesting), and you have to manually open single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the python regex that I use for my Latex documents:

```
'([ \w-]+)'", " `\\1'
```

There is a python script that applies the regex on a latex file ([here](http://david-web.appspot.com/cnt/LatexQuotes/)). Works most of the time. Happy typesetting! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some Perl regular expression substitutions that might be good enough for what you want to do.

```
s/"(\w)/``$1/g;
s/'(\w)/`$1/g;
s/([\w\.?!])"/$1''/g;
```

The code assumes that a single or double quote followed by an alphanumeric character begins a quote.  Also, it assumes that a double quote following an alphanumeric character or punctuation mark ends a quote. These assumptions are probably true most of the time but there may be exceptions.

Comment: This is similar to what I used in the past. Needs human intervention from time to time, but takes up most of the work...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the input - helpful and appreciated.

I've also come across this, from CPAN's [Latex::Encode.pm](http://search.cpan.org/src/ANDREWF/LaTeX-Encode-0.03/lib/LaTeX/Encode.pm):

```
    # A single or double quote before a word character, preceded
    # by start of line, whitespace or punctuation gets converted
    # to "`" or "``" respectively.

    $text =~ s{ ( ^ | [\s\p{IsPunct}] )( ['"] ) (?= \w ) }
              { $2 eq '"' ? "$1``" : "$1`" }mgxe;

    # A double quote preceded by a word or punctuation character
    # and followed by whitespace or end of line gets converted to
    # "''".  (Final single quotes are represented by themselves so
    # we don't need to worry about those.)

    $text =~ s{ (?<= [\w\p{IsPunct}] ) " (?= \s | $ ) }
              { "''" }mgxe
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use regular expressions for this kind of task!

Maybe you can get some inspiration from [SmartyPants](http://daringfireball.net/projects/smartypants/)?

Comment: ... looking for a Python version, now. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to this problem and decided to learn a little lisp today. I put this lisp function in my ~/.emacs file and then run with `M-x tex-set-quotes`:

```
(defun tex-set-quotes ()  
  (interactive)  
  (latex-mode)  
  (while (search-forward "\"" nil t)  
   (replace-match "" nil t)  
   (tex-insert-quote nil)))
```

Answer (score -4):

Simply, use `` for opening quotations and '' for closing