# Gedit highlight (gtksourceview): how to highlight a block inside [curly] braces with a color

Tags: syntax-highlighting, gedit, gtksourceview

I need to highlight every whole block of code that is inside curly braces, so I created a rule:

```
<context id="action-body" style-ref="action-body" extend-parent="true">
   <start>{</start>
   <end>}</end>
   <include>
      <context ref="builtin-vars" />
      <context ref="keywords" />
   </include>
</context>
```

It highlights code, keywords and vars inside correctly, but it of course stops if there is another closing curly bracket inside. I know that it is not trivial for regular expressions to check level of recursion, but may be `gtkSourceView` syntax has something special for cases like these?

It is a serious thing, because a language (PegJS, in fact) I am making highlighting for can contain JavaScript code only inside curly braces, not outside. And I want to highlight them with one color exluding :)

---

Related:

- [Regex to get string between curly braces "{I want what's between the curly braces}"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413071/regex-to-get-string-between-curly-braces-i-want-whats-between-the-curly-braces)
- [How can I extract a string between matching braces in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700613/how-can-i-extract-a-string-between-matching-braces-in-perl)

Answer (score 1):

This way ([from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700613/how-can-i-extract-a-string-between-matching-braces-in-perl)) highlights ok (gedit goes a little slow when cursor in braces) when such syntax is used on a single line, but not for multi-line:

```
<context id="action-body" style-ref="action-body">
   <match>(\{(?:[^{}]*|(?0))*\})</match>
   <!-- <include>
      <context ref="builtin-vars"/>
      <context ref="keywords"/>
   </include> -->
</context>
```

(and it do not allows me to use included contexts, but the [spec](http://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/lang-reference.html) says I can :( )

Comment: The spec only says you can use included contexts in a container context. A container context may contain `<start>` and `<end>`, but not `<match>`.