# extract contents of each level of parentheses

Tags: regex, perl, grammar, speech, parentheses

I am converting a [SMAPI](http://www.wizzardsoftware.com/docs/smapi%20developers%20guide.pdf) grammar to [JSGF](http://www.w3.org/TR/jsgf/#16460). They are pretty similar grammars used in different speech recognition systems. SMAPI uses a question mark they way the rest of the world does, to mean 0 or 1 of the previous thing. JSGF uses square brackets for this. So, I need to convert a string like `stuff?` to `[stuff]`, and parenthesized strings like `((((stuff)? that)? I)? like)?` to `[[[[stuff] that] I] like]`. I have to leave alone strings like `((((stuff) that) I) hate)`. As Qtax pointed out, a more complicated example would be `(foo ((bar)? (baz))?)` being replaced by `(foo [[bar] (baz)])`.

Because of this, I have to extract every level of a parenthesized expression, see if it ends in a question mark, and replace the parens and question mark with square braces if it does.
I think Eric Strom's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700613/how-can-i-extract-a-string-between-matching-braces-in-perl) question is almost what I need. The problem is that when I use it, it returns the largest matched grouping, whereas I need to do operations on each individual groupings.

This is what I have so far: `s/( \( (?: [^()?]* | (?0) )* \) ) \?/[$1]/xg`. When matched with `((((stuff)? that)? I)? like)?`, however, it produces only `[((((stuff)? that)? I)? like)]`. Any ideas on how to do this?

I

Comment: Instead of regex, can you just use a string replace to replace `(` with `[` and `)?` with `]`?

Comment: Your title says you need to extract contents of parentheses, but your text says you need to convert parentheses to square brackets. Which is it?

Comment: I edited the question to reflect my intentions better.

Comment: I guess a better example would be: `(foo ((bar)? (baz))?)` to `(foo [[bar] (baz)])`

Comment: @Qtax: yes! I guess I should place that in my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve it in a couple of ways, simplest being just executing your expression till there are no more replacements made. E.g:

```
1 while s/( \( (?: [^()?]* | (?0) )* \) ) \?/[$1]/xg;
```

But that is highly inefficient (for deeply nested strings).

You could do it in one pass like this instead:

```
s{
  (?(DEFINE)
    (?<r>   \( (?: [^()]++ | (?&r) )*+ \)   )
  )

  ( \( )
  (?=   (?: [^()]++ | (?&r) )*+ \) \?   )

  |

  \) \?
}{
  $2? '[': ']'
}gex;
```

Comment: The 1 while thing works great! How come giving the regex the g swith didn't do the same thing? However, given `<testMe> = ((((stuff)? that)? I)? like)?`, your regex gives me `<testMe> = ]]]]stuff] that] I] like]` for some reason.

Comment: @NateGlenn, works now, changed `$1` to `$2`. (Forgot to count the recursive group, doh.)

Comment: Though some comments on it would be nice... It's far beyond my regex abilities.

Comment: @NateGlenn - This will not work if there is `?` in text, like for example with text `((((stu?ff)? that)? I)? like)?`

Comment: @user1215106: If it were true, how likely are you to have a ? in a speech recognition grammar anyway? Recognition grammars generally have no punctuation, outside of dashes and apostrophes, which are legitimate within a word.

Answer (score 4):

You'll also want to look at [ysth's solution to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2700668/168657), and use a tool that is already available to solve this problem:

```
use Text::Balanced qw(extract_bracketed);
$text = '((((stuff)? that)? I)? like)?';

for ($i=0; $i<length($text); $i++) {
    ($match,$remainder) = extract_bracketed( substr($text,$i), '()' );
    if ($match && $remainder =~ /^\?/) {
        substr($text,$i) =
            '[' . substr($match,1,-1) . ']' . substr($remainder,1);
        $i=-1; # fixed
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ωmega, nice how? This version doesn't work at all even with the OPs original example. (Result is `[[([stuff] that)? I] like]`.) For that simple example, the first version worked, but it's no good since it fails with a proper example, like `(foo ((bar)? (baz))?)`, result `(foo[([bar] (baz]?)`. Doesn't work for anything, -1 till fixed.

Answer (score 2):

In older Perl versions (pre 5.10), one could have used code assertions and dynamic regex for this:

```
 ...
 my $s = '((((stuff)? that)? I)? like)?';

 # recursive dynamic regex, we need
 # to pre-declare lexical variables
 my $rg;

 # use a dynamically generated regex (??{..})
 # and a code assertion (?{..})
 $rg = qr{
          (?:                       # start expression
           (?> [^)(]+)              # (a) we don't see any (..) => atomic!
            |                       # OR 
           (                        # (b) start capturing group for level
            \( (??{$rg}) \) \?      # oops, we found parentheses \(,\) w/sth 
           )                        # in between and the \? at the end
           (?{ print "[ $^N ]\n" }) # if we got here, print the captured text $^N
          )*                        # done, repeat expression if possible
         }xs;

 $s =~ /$rg/;
 ...
```

during the match, the code assertion prints all matches, which are:

```
 [ (stuff)? ]
 [ ((stuff)? that)? ]
 [ (((stuff)? that)? I)? ]
 [ ((((stuff)? that)? I)? like)? ]
```

To use this according to your requirements, you could change the code assertion slightly, put the capturing parentheses at the right place, and save the matches in an array:

```
 ...
 my @result;
 my $rg;
 $rg = qr{
          (?:                      
           (?> [^)(]+)             
            |                      
            \( ( (??{$rg}) ) \) \?  (?{ push @result, $^N })
          )*                     
         }xs;

 $s =~ /$rg/ && print map "[$_]\n", @result;
 ...
```

which says:

```
 [stuff]
 [(stuff)? that]
 [((stuff)? that)? I]
 [(((stuff)? that)? I)? like]
```

Regards

rbo