# Perl: How to extract a string between brackets

Tags: perl, matching

I have a file in moinmoin text format:

```
* [[  Virtualbox Guest Additions]] (2011/10/17 15:19)
* [[  Abiword Wordprocessor]] (2010/10/27 20:17)
* [[  Sylpheed E-Mail]] (2010/03/30 21:49)
* [[   Kupfer]] (2010/05/16 20:18)
```

All the words between the '[[' and ']]' are the short description of the entry.  I need to extract the whole entry, but not each individual word.

I found an answer for a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2700749/819596
but can't understand the answer: `"my @array = $str =~ /( \{ (?: [^{}]* | (?0) )* \} )/xg;"`

Anything that works will be accepted but explanations would help greatly, ie: what `(?0)` or  `/xg` does.

Comment: thanks for answers gonna take a nap and try out the answers!

Answer (score 2):

The code probably will look like this:

```
use warnings; 
use strict;

my @subjects; # declaring a lexical variable to store all the subjects
my $pattern = qr/ 
  \[ \[    # matching two `[` signs
  \s*      # ... and, if any, whitespace after them
  ([^]]+) # starting from the first non-whitespace symbol, capture all the non-']' symbols
  ]]
/x;

# main processing loop:
while (<DATA>) { # reading the source file line by line
  if (/$pattern/) {      # if line is matched by our pattern
    push @subjects, $1;  # ... push the captured group of symbols into our array
  }
}
print $_, "\n" for @subjects; # print our array of subject line by line

__DATA__
* [[  Virtualbox Guest Additions]] (2011/10/17 15:19)
* [[  Abiword Wordprocessor]] (2010/10/27 20:17)
* [[  Sylpheed E-Mail]] (2010/03/30 21:49)
* [[   Kupfer]] (2010/05/16 20:18)
```

As I see, what you need can be described as follows: in each line of file try to find this sequence of symbols...

```
[[, an opening delimiter, 
then 0 or more whitespace symbols,
then all the symbols that make a subject (which should be saved),
then ]], a closing delimiter
```

As you see, this description quite naturally translates into a regex. The only thing that is probably not needed is `/x` regex modifier, which allowed me to extensively comment it. )

Answer (score 2):

If the text will never contain `]`, you can simply use the following as previously recommended:

```
/\[\[ ( [^\]]* ) \]\]/x
```

The following allows `]` in the contained text, but I recommend against incorporating it into a larger pattern:

```
/\[\[ ( .*? ) \]\]/x
```

The following allows `]` in the contained text, and is the most robust solution:

```
/\[\[ ( (?:(?!\]\]).)* ) \]\]/x
```

For example,

```
if (my ($match) = $line =~ /\[\[ ( (?:(?!\]\]).)* ) \]\]/x) {
   print "$match\n";
}
```

or

```
my @matches = $file =~ /\[\[ ( (?:(?!\]\]).)* ) \]\]/xg;
```

---

- `/x`: Ignore whitespace in pattern. Allows spaces to be added to make the pattern readable without changing the meaning of the pattern. Documented in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).
- `/g`: Find all matches. Documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).
- `(?0)` was used to make the pattern recursive since the linked node had to deal with arbitrary nesting of curlies. * `/g`: Find all matches. Documented in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
\[\[(.*)]]
```

`\[` is a literal [, 
`]` is a literal ],
`.*` means every sequence of 0 or more character,
something enclosed in parentheses is a capturing group, hence you can access it later in your script with $1 (or $2 .. $9 depending on how many groups you have).

Put all together you will match two `[` then everything up to the last occurrence of two successive `]`

*Update*
On a second read of your question I suddenly are confused, do you need the content between [[ and ]], or the whole line - in that case leave the parentheses out completely and just test if the pattern matches, no need to capture.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you found is for recursive pattern matching, that i think you don't need.

- /x allows to use meaningless spaces and comments in the regexp.
- /g runs the regexp through all the string. Without it runs only till the first match.
- /xg is /x and /g combined.
- (?0) runs the regexp itself again (recursion)

If i understand ok, you need something like this:

```
$text="* [[  Virtualbox Guest Additions]] (2011/10/17 15:19)
* [[  Abiword Wordprocessor]] (2010/10/27 20:17)
* [[  Sylpheed E-Mail]] (2010/03/30 21:49)
* [[   Kupfer]] (2010/05/16 20:18)
";

@array=($text=~/\[\[([^\]]*)\]\]/g);
print join(",",@array);

# this prints "  Virtualbox Guest Additions,  Abiword Wordprocessor,  Sylpheed E-Mail,   Kupfer"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using "extract_bracketed" or "extract_delimited" from module Text::Balanced - see here: http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Balanced.html

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pe 's/.*\[\[(.*)\]\].*/\1/g' temp
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
        * [[  Virtualbox Guest Additions]] (2011/10/17 15:19)
        * [[  Abiword Wordprocessor]] (2010/10/27 20:17)
        * [[  Sylpheed E-Mail]] (2010/03/30 21:49)
        * [[   Kupfer]] (2010/05/16 20:18)
>
> perl -pe 's/.*\[\[(.*)\]\].*/\1/g' temp
  Virtualbox Guest Additions
  Abiword Wordprocessor
  Sylpheed E-Mail
   Kupfer
>
```

- s/.*[[(.*)]].*/\1/g
- .*[[->match any charater till [[
- (.*)]] store any charater after the string "[[" till "]]" in \1
- .*->matching the rest of the line.

then since we have our data in \1 we can simply use it for printing on the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
my @array = $str =~ /( \{ (?: [^{}]* | (?0) )* \} )/xg;
```

The 'x' flag means that whitespace is ignored in the regex, to allow for a more readable expression. The 'g' flag means that the result will be a list of all matches from left to right (match *g*lobally).

The `(?0)` represents the regular expression inside the first group of parentheses. It's a recursive regular expression, equivalent to a set of rules such as:

```
E := '{' ( NoBrace | E) '}'
NoBrace := [^{}]*
```