# Bash: need to find text within matching braces (parantheses) in text

Tags: regex, bash, pattern-matching

I have some text that looks like this:

```
(something1)something2
```

However something1 and something2 might also have some parentheses inside them such as

```
(some(thing)1)something(2)
```

I want to extract `something1` (including internal parentheses if there are any) to a variable.  Since I can count on the text always starting with an opening parentheses, I'm hoping that I can do something where I match the first parenthesis to the correct closing parentheses, and extract the middle.

Everything I have tried so far has the potential to match the wrong ending parentheses.

Comment: It is provably impossible to find matching parentheses with a regular expression, so an approach like searching through the string character by character until the number of open and close parentheses are equal is probably the best way to go

Comment: @Angelo Perl regular expressions (which, strictly speaking, aren't true regular expressions, because they are more powerful) can match parentheses, and are supported by `grep` (GNU `grep`, at least).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl regular expression: match nested brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301708/perl-regular-expression-match-nested-brackets)

Comment: While perl can do this with a regex, it is possible to do this in bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have perl, the:

```
perl -MText::Balanced -nlE 'say [Text::Balanced::extract_bracketed( $_, "()" )]->[0]' <<EOF
(something1)something2
(some(thing)1)something(2)
(some(t()()hing)()1)()something(2)
EOF
```

will prints

```
(something1)
(some(thing)1)
(some(t()()hing)()1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this is apparently something that is impossible with regular expressions, I have resorted to pickup the the characters 1 by 1:

```
    first=""
count=0
while test -n "$string"
do
    char=${string:0:1}  # Get the first character
    if [[ "$char" == ")" ]]
    then
        count=$(( $count - 1 ))
    fi
    if [[ $count > 0 ]]
    then
        first="$first$char"
    fi
    if [[ "$char" == "(" ]]
    then
        count=$(( $count + 1 ))
    fi
    string=${string:1}  # Trim the first character
    if [[ $count == 0 ]]
    then
        second="$string"
        string=""
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with perl:

```
echo "(some(thing)1)something(2)" | perl -ne '$_ =~ /(\((?:\(.*\)|[^(])*\))|\w+/s; print $1;'
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` can do it:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
{
   for (i=1; i<=length; ++i) {
      if (numLeft == 0 && substr($0, i, 1) == "(") {
         leftPos = i
         numLeft = 1
      } else if (substr($0, i, 1) == "(") {
         ++numLeft
      } else if (substr($0, i, 1) == ")") {
         ++numRight
      }
      if (numLeft && numLeft == numRight) {
         print substr($0, leftPos, i-leftPos+1)
         next
      }
   }
}
```

Input:

```
(something1)something2
(some(thing)1)something(2)
```

Output:

```
(something1)
(some(thing)1)
```