# Ways to include a dynamically generated facelet

Tags: java, jsf, dynamic, facelets, el

In current project I need to create a panel that will contain an HTML content created by the user elsewhere in the application. This content can be easily inserted like this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.dynamicHTMLContent}" escape="false"/>
```

An example content:

```
<p>User text</p>
```

Now we need to give the user more freedom and allow him to use tokens in the HTML code that will be resolved by the application later:

```
<p>User text</p><p>User image: {niceImage}</p>
```

The application parses user content in *myBean.dynamicHTMLContent* and replaces *{niceImage(param)}* with

```
<a4j:mediaOutput element="img" createContent="{myBean.generateNiceImage}"/>
```

This is already a facelet snippet and cannot be evaluated and rendered in *h:outputText*.

I was looking for a good way to include this kind of dynamic content within a facelet at the stage when EL expressions are not yet evaluated. Something like

```
<ui:include src="src"/>
```

but for dynamic components would be the best solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I took the easy way by replacing all custom (curly braces) tokens in the user HTML with corresponding JSF elements and generating a temporary `ui:composition` facelet file:

```
public String getUserHtmlContentPath() {

   File temp = File.createTempFile("userContent", ".tmp");
   temp.deleteOnExit();

   FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(temp);
   fw.write(getUserHtmlContentComposition());
   fw.close();

   return "file://" + temp.getAbsolutePath(); 
}
```

and in the parent facelet:

```
<ui:include src="#{myBean.userHtmlContentPath}"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [user423943](https://stackoverflow.com/users/423943/user423943) in the idea of creating a component for that. However, I would extend the `<h:outputText>` instead. In your case, you will not have a lot of work to do. First, create a `my.taglib.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN" "facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">
<facelet-taglib>
    <namespace>http://my.components/jsf</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>myComponent</tag-name>
        <component>
            <component-type>my.component.myComponent</component-type>
            <renderer-type>my.renderkit.myComponent</renderer-type>
        </component>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

This file just need to be present in the classpath of your application and it will be loaded automatically by Facelets (because it ends with `.taglib.xml`).

Then, in the `faces-config.xml` defines the Java classes for this component:

```
<component>
    <component-type>my.component.myComponent</component-type>
    <component-class>my.package.component.MyHtmlComponent</component-class>
</component>
<render-kit>
    <render-kit-id>HTML_BASIC</render-kit-id>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>javax.faces.Output</component-family>
        <renderer-type>my.renderkit.myComponent</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>my.package.component.MyHtmlComponentRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
```

Then, you will have to create two classes:

- `my.package.component.MyHtmlComponent` that will extend `javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText` and do nothing more.
- `my.package.component.MyHtmlComponentRenderer` that will extend the `com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TextRenderer` class.

Your renderer class will do all the job, by generating the HTML code for the value of your component, exactly as the `<h:outputText>` does. You can have a look at `HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(FacesContext, UIComponent)` and `TextRenderer.getEndTextToRender(FacesContext, UIComponent, String)` methods, that are involved in this part.
Of course, when you are facing a `{niceImage}` code in your text, you simply need to generate a HTML `img` tag. For that, you can use the adequate methods of the `ResponseWriter` to build an HTML tag and attributes:

```
writer.startElement("img", component);
writer.writeAttribute("src", urlToImage);
writer.endElement("img");
```

Once everything is created, you have to use your new component in your JSF page:

```
<html xmlns:my="http://my.components/jsf">
    ...
    <my:myComponent value="#{myBean.dynamicHTMLContent}" escape="false"/>
    ...
```

---

Two links that can help you in addition to the ones provided by user423943:

http://www.jsftutorials.net/helpDesk/standardRenderKit_component-class_renderer-slass.html

http://www.jsftutorials.net/helpDesk/standardRenderKit_component-type_renderer-type.html

You will find, for all HTML JSF components their types and classes.

Comment: This is definitely the best solution for simple cases like including an image or a link. However if we need to support virtually any possible facelet component, it's better to offload these tasks to JSF engine. In my case I was avoiding duplicating code which was already in a4j:mediaOutput because the image that replaces the token is generated dynamically on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

What makes this complex, I think, is that `#{myBean.dynamicHTMLContent}` isn't quite HTML content but JSF content.  I think the most flexible solution would be to write your own JSF component.  Perhaps someone will  correct me, but I don't think there's a way to replace text like `{niceImage}` JSF code.

There's some articles about this:

- http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364786/Building-Custom-JSF-UI-Components
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jsf1/
- http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364786/Building-Custom-JSF-UI-Components
- http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnavh.html
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf4/
- https://matthiaswessendorf.wordpress.com/2008/02/29/custom-jsf-components-with-facelets/

I'm no JSF expert, but you could probably:

- extend `org.ajax4jsf.MediaOutput`
- [parse out all the text in curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413071/regex-to-get-string-between-curly-braces-i-want-whats-between-the-curly-braces)
- replace things like `niceImage` with references to `#{myBean.generateNiceImage}` or whatever
- forward the actual work to the superclass, `org.ajax4jsf.MediaOutput`

Hope that helps!

Comment: I was thinking about creating a custom JSF component, but the amount of work with JSF internals cannot be really justified by the simple job the component should do. It's the same <ui:include/> but a dynamic one. So I decided to create a temporary file and use <ui:include/> to include it into the facelet.

Comment: I agree that a creation of a component is the best solution (maybe not by extending the `MediaOutput`). See my answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `includeFacelet(UIComponent, URL)` also for including dynamically generated facelets. The trick is using the `data` URL scheme and a custom `URLStreamHandler`:

```
String encoded = Base64.encodeBase64String(myDynamicFacelet.getBytes());
context.includeFacelet(uiComponent, new URL(null, "data://text/plain;base64," + encoded, new DataStreamHandler()));
```

If you have a generic handler for `data://` URLs, it's the best option to use. I needed a handler only for this specific use case, so it's pretty limited:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLStreamHandler;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class DataStreamHandler extends URLStreamHandler {

  private static class DataURLConnection extends URLConnection {

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
      return new ByteArrayInputStream(this.content.getBytes());
    }

    private static String PREFIX = "data://text/plain;base64,";
    private static int PREFIX_LEN = PREFIX.length();

    protected DataURLConnection(URL url) {
      super(url);
      this.url = url;

      String encoded = this.url.toString().substring(PREFIX_LEN);
      this.content = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(encoded));
    }

    @Override
    public void connect() throws IOException {
      // Do nothing
    }

    private URL url;
    private String content;
  }

  @Override
  protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
    return new DataURLConnection(url);
  }
}
```