# How to grab content from between two double brackets

Tags: regex

I have RegEx that I believe should work, but isn't.

I would like to grab 'test' out of [[test]].

I have tried:

```
\[\[(\w+)\]\]
\[\[([A-z]*?)\]\]
\[\[(.*?)\]\]
```

All of which just grab the whole thing. Meaning, it grabs [[test]], instead of just the content. I am unsure how to get a regex that will grab JUST 'test' and not the brackets.

Comment: I would recommend looking at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026685/regex-to-get-text-between-two-characters

Comment: Reading this right now!

Comment: What language are you using?  If it's C# you `do` have to escape the brackets

Comment: I am using Racket's regexp. But, I am testing this all with regexpal.com, and can not for the life of me come up with a solution that doesn't include the brackets with it. It seems to simple, yet it isn't.

Comment: What's the ultimate purpose of the regex?  Just find some text or do you want to find it and replace the brackets?

Comment: Ultimate purpose is to grab text from between beginning and ending double brackets. Which doesn't require double brackets being in my regex at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this ?

```
\[\[(.+)\]\]
```

It might be a good idea to specify which language you are using.
That will determine of you need to escape the brackets.

this worked on http://regexpal.com/ it will simply match the word characters if that is all you need.

```
\w+
```

Comment: This is still grabbing both brackets from the beginning and end

Comment: This does work! Thank you. For some reason I kept trying to use [[ before the part I wanted to grab (which is always word characters) and couldn't get that to work. Was making it more complicated than it needed to be.

Answer (score 0):

you must remove the backslashes. brackets don't need to be escaped and you can group parts of the pattern expression enclosing them with "(" and ")":

```
[[\(\w\w*\)]]
```

or

```
\[\[\([A-z][A-z]*\)\]\]
```

or

```
\[\[[A-z][A-z]*\]\]
```

will work correctly.

Comment: None of these seem to work. It ends up not catching on anything.

Comment: @emab out of curiousity are these examples for `Java`?