# Getting content between curly braces in JavaScript with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to get content between curly braces with JavaScript. I found this thread: [Regex to get string between curly braces "{I want what's between the curly braces}"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413071/regex-to-get-string-between-curly-braces-i-want-whats-between-the-curly-braces)

But I do not know how to apply a regex like `/\{([^}]+)\}/`

I have tried `string.replace('/\{([^}]+)\}/','');`, however this does not work.

Answer (score 41):

Here's an example of use:

```
var found = [],          // an array to collect the strings that are found
    rxp = /{([^}]+)}/g,
    str = "a {string} with {curly} braces",
    curMatch;

while( curMatch = rxp.exec( str ) ) {
    found.push( curMatch[1] );
}

console.log( found );    // ["string", "curly"]
```

Comment: nice regex. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
/[^{\}]+(?=})/g
```

for example

> Welcome to RegExr v2.1 by {gskinner.com}, {ssd.sd} hosted by Media Temple!

it will return 'gskinner.com', 'ssd.sd'

Answer (score 6):

Like this?

```
var x="omg {wtf} bbq";

alert(x.match(/{([^}]+)}/));
```

Comment: That returns `{wtf},wtf` rather than `wtf`

Comment: Get the first group, it will contain just the text between the braces. Keep in mind that parentheses in a regex define groups.

Comment: How can I remove the groups all together and just have it return `wtf`

Comment: just tested in Firefox and Chrome, what error do you get and are you using the same test-case scenario as me ?

Answer (score 2):

```
"{I want what's between the curly braces}".replace(/{(.*)}/, "$1");
```

this should work, cheers.

Note: you'll "get everything" in the braces, even if it's an empty string.

***Updated:***
If you are going to match the first character which in the middle of a string, use "match":

```
"how are you {I want what's between the curly braces} words".match(/{(.*)}/)[1];
```

You can just do:

```
console.log("how are you {I want what's between the curly braces} words".match(/{(.*)}/));
```

then you'll see a list of the match items, exploit them to whatever you want.

Gory details: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: @alex what version of IE are you using? I've just tested it in IE9, like this: http://img801.imageshack.us/i/reie.png/, actually I did IE7, 8 as well, all work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This will return an array of matching text.
the map function will return the text without `{}`.

```js
const text = "Regex to get string between curly braces {I want what's between the curly braces}"
const result = text.match(/{([^}]+)}/g)
  .map(res => res.replace(/{|}/g , ''))
```