# Get Text between parenthesis using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get value between multiple curly braces that startwith {{

eg :

```
var txt ="I expect five hundred dollars {{$500}}. and new brackets {{$600}}";
```

Expected Result : `array of result like result[0] = "{{$500}}", result[1] = "{{$600}}"`

I tried below thing, but it does not return expected result

```
var regExp = /\{([^)]+)\}/g;
var result = txt.match(regExp);
```

[JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/mnsvp6qn/1/)

Comment: does it need to be with regular expression?

Comment: @Zorkind no it can be anything, even plain JS

Comment: it is getting everything inside the first "{" and the last "}"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting content between curly braces in javascript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520880/getting-content-between-curly-braces-in-javascript-regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple regex like [`/{{\w+:(\$\d+)}}/g`](https://regex101.com/r/JHjYAB/2), then get each match using [`RegExp#exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) function and extract the value from the captured group.

```js
var txt = "I expect five hundred dollars {{rc:$500}}. and new brackets {{ac:$600}}";

var reg = /{{\w+:(\$\d+)}}/g,
  m,
  res = [],
  res2 = [];

while (m = reg.exec(txt)) {
  res.push(m[0]);
  res2.push(m[1]);
}

console.log(res,res2)
```

Comment: @Richa : `/{{rc(\$\d+)}}/g`

Comment: @Richa :  `/{{rc:(\$\d+)}}/g`

Comment: @Richa share the expected result

Comment: @Richa :  you can update the regex as per your requirement, you can use your own regex which matches combination of anything other than parenthesis in between curly braces

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mnsvp6qn/3/ not working in updated fiddle. Am i missing something

Comment: @Richa : let me check

Answer (score 1):

Use `match` and `map`, regex as `/(?:({{))[^}]+(?=}})/g`

```
var txt ="I expect five hundred dollars {{ac:$500}}. and new brackets {{ac:$600}}";
var matches = txt.match( /(?:({{))[^}]+(?=}})/g );
if ( matches )
{
   matches = matches.map( s => s.substring(2) );
}
console.log( matches  );
```

**Demo**

```js
var txt ="I expect five hundred dollars {{ac:$500}}. and new brackets {{ac:$600}}";
var matches = txt.match(/(?:({{))[^}]+(?=}})/g);
if (matches) {
  matches = matches.map(s => s.substring(2));
}
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you code like this

```js
var txt ="I expect five hundred dollars {{$500}}. and new brackets {{$600}}";
function getText(str) {
  var res = [], p = /{{([^}]+)}}/g, row;

  while(row = p.exec(str)) {
    res.push(row[1]);
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(getText(txt));
```

Answer (score 0):

`String#match` will always return the full matched regular expression without using capture groups. You could use `String#replace` with a callback function to add each match to an array.

```js
var txt ="I expect five hundred dollars {{ac:$500}}. and new brackets {{ac:$600}}";

var regExp = /{{ac:([^\}]+)}}/g;

function matches(regExp, txt) {
  const result = []
  txt.replace(regExp, (_, x) => result.push(x));
  return result
}

console.log(matches(regExp, txt))
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```