# Simple Javascript string manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a string that will look something like this:

```
I'm sorry the code "codehere" is not valid
```

I need to get the value inside the quotes inside the string.  So essentially I need to get the codehere and store it in a variable.

After some researching it looks like I could loop through the string and use .charAt(i) to find the quotes and then pull the string out one character at a time in between the quotes.

However I feel there has to be a simpler solution for this out there.  Any input would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: This question may be of some use

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413071/regex-to-get-string-between-curly-braces-i-want-whats-between-the-curly-braces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) to get the position of the quotes:

```
var openQuote  = myString.indexOf('"'),
    closeQuote = myString.lastIndexOf('"');
```

Then you can validate they are not the same position, and use [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to retrieve the code:

```
var code = myString.substring(openQuote, closeQuote + 1);
```

Comment: Just on a side note - `substring` (as opposed to `substr`) accepts start and end so it could be a little bit more straightforward: `myString.substring(openQuote, closeQuote + 1)`. (The +1 is actually also obligatory in `substr` - now it does not contain the last `"`).

Comment: perfect!  I don't know if I was clear enough in what I was asking for judging by the other answers, but this one was what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: What if the string is something like this `I'm sorry the code "codehere" is not valid, "codethere" is valid`

Comment: @ShankarSangoli - If that is the case then I agree, you need to use another method such as regular expressions. It depends on the application and where the string is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

Regex:

```
var a = "I'm sorry the code \"codehere\" is not valid";
var m = a.match(/"[^"]*"/ig);
alert(m[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var str = "I'm sorry the code \"cod\"eh\"ere\" is not valid";
alert(str.replace(/^[^"]*"(.*)".*$/g, "$1"));
```

Comment: What if there is nothing that matches that pattern? then the whole string will be returned?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Javascript's [match](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) function. It takes as parameter, a regular expression. Eg:

`/\".*\"/`

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions! You can find a match using a simple regular expressions like `/"(.+)"/` with the Javascript `RegExp()` object. Fore more info see [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

Comment: w3schools contains lots of errors, I would not advise to use it.

Comment: You probably shouldn't recommend w3schools.  A lot of their material is misleading and sometimes downright incorrect. See.. http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var msg = "I'm sorry the code \"codehere\" is not valid";
var matchedContent = msg.match(/\".*\"/ig);
//matchedContent is an array
alert(matchedContent[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). This is a text pattern matcher that is built into the javascript language. Regular expressions look like this: `/thing to match/flags`* for example, `/"(.*)"/`, which matches everything between a set of quotes.

Beware, regular expressions are limited -- they can't match nested things, so if the value inside quotes contains quotes itself, you'll end up with a big ugly mess.

*: or `new RegExp(...)`, but use the literal syntax; it's better.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the `.split()` string function:

```
var mystring = 'I\'m sorry the code "codehere" is not valid' ;
var tokens = [] ;
var strsplit = mystring.split('\"') ;
for(var i=0;i<strsplit.length;i++) {
    if((i % 2)==0) continue;    // Ignore strings outside the quotes
    tokens.push(strsplit[i]) ;  // Store strings inside quotes.
}

// Output:
// tokens[0] = 'codehere' ;
```