# javascript, regex parse string content in curly brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, string-parsing

i am new to regex. I am trying to parse all contents inside curly brackets in a string. I looked up [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413071/regex-to-get-string-between-curly-braces-i-want-whats-between-the-curly-brace) as a reference and did exactly as one of the answers suggest, however the result is unexpected.

Here is what i did

```
var abc = "test/abcd{string1}test{string2}test" //any string
var regex = /{(.+?)}/
regex.exec(abc) // i got ["{string1}", "string1"]
             //where i am expecting ["string1", "string2"]
```

i think i am missing something, what am i doing wrong?

**update**

i was able to get it with `/g` for a global search

```
var regex = /{(.*?)}/g
abc.match(regex) //gives ["{string1}", "{string2}"]
```

how can i get the string w/o brackets?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
"test/abcd{string1}test{string2}test".match(/[^{}]+(?=\})/g)
```

produces

```
["string1", "string2"]
```

It assumes that every `}` has a corresponding `{` before it and `{...}` sections do not nest.  It will also not capture the content of empty `{}` sections.

Comment: This is good. But you do not need to escape the closing brace. `/[^{}]+(?=})/g`

Comment: How do the same with this braces? [ ]

Comment: @AuthorProxy, to include `[` or `]` in a character set, escape them.  `[\[\]]` is a character set with only the square brackets.

Comment: @MikeSamuel it doesn't work, check at any online regexp

Comment: @AuthorProxy I did.  `/[\[\]]+/.exec('a[[]]b')[0] === '[[]]'` is true in JS.

Answer (score 3):

```
var abc = "test/abcd{string1}test{string2}test" //any string
var regex = /{(.+?)}/g
var matches;

while(matches = regex.exec(abc))
    console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var abc = "test/abcd{string1}test{string2}test" //any string
var regex = /{(.+?)}/g //g flag so the regex is global
abc.match(regex) //find every match
```

a good place to read about Regex in javascript is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), and a nice place to test is [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

good luck!

Comment: I don't think g would make a difference here. It is not getting the second match (string2) because it is calling exec only once.

Comment: @Kash you're right, but I called match, and without the g, it will return `["{string1}", "string1"]`

Answer (score 1):

This result:

```
["{string1}", "string1"]
```

is showing you that for the first match, the entire regex matched `"{string1}"` and the first capturing parentheses matched `"string1"`.

If you want to get all matches and see all capturing parens of each match, you can use the "g" flag and loop through, calling `exec()` multiple times like this:

```
var abc = "test/abcd{string1}test{string2}test"; //any string
var regex = /{(.+?)}/g;
var match, results = [];
while (match = regex.exec(abc)) {
    results.push(match[1]);   // save first captured parens sub-match into results array
}

// results == ["string1", "string2"]
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/sapfm/

Comment: assignment in a condition... not my cup of tea.

Comment: It's an efficient way to do this type of loop and somewhat common for this exact purpose.  I would generally avoid it too, except in this type of case.  You can take a couple more lines of code to accomplish the same thing without it if you want.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, i was wondering why the same string appeared twice. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong. But you'll need to look at your capturing groups (the second element in the array) to get the content you wanted (you can ignore the first). To get all occurences, it's not enough to run `exec` once, you'll need to loop over the results using `match`.

*Edit*: nevermind that, afaik you can't access capturing groups with `match`. A simpler solution would be using a positive lookahead, as Mike Samuel [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9792527/520779).

Answer (score 1):

try this for file

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('logs.txt', function(err, data) {
if(err) throw err;
const paragraph = "'" + data + "'";
const regex = /\d+\<;>\S+\<;>(\d+)\<;/g;
const found = paragraph.match(regex);

console.log(found);
})
```