# How to get a specific string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
var text = 'LTE CSSR (East xr) (301-LT_King_St_PC)'
```

and I want to split from **(East xr) (301-LT_King_St_PC)** only as follow :

```
var result = text.split('(')
result = (East xr) (301-LT_King_St_PC)
```

Comment: So, in words, you want "Everything after (and including) the first open bracket `(`"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript, regex parse string content in curly brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792427/javascript-regex-parse-string-content-in-curly-brackets). It's not exactly clear what your end result should be. Could you post more examples of inputs/outputs or explain the logic to translate from `text` to `result`?

Comment: @DBS
 yes, Everything between the first '(' and the second ')'

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression with the `match` function to get this done. Depending on how you want the result try one of the following:

```js
var text = 'LTE CSSR (East xr) (301-LT_King_St_PC)'
console.log('one string:', text.match(/\(.*\)/)[0])
console.log('array of strings:', text.match(/\([^\)]*\)/g))
```

The first does what you seem to be asking for - a single output of everything between the first ( and the second ). It does this by searching for `/\(.*\)/` which is a regex that says "everything in between the parentheses".

The second `match` splits it into all parenthesised strings using `/\([^\)]*\)/g` which is a regex that says "each parenthesised string" but the `g` at the end says "all of those" so an array of each is given.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) :

```js
var text = 'LTE CSSR (East xr) (301-LT_King_St_PC)';
var result = text.substring(text.indexOf('('));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're quite close with your current method. One way you could try this is to use multiple characters within your split

```
var result = text.split(") (") 
# Output -> result = ["(East xr", "301-LT_King_St_PC)"]
```

From here, some string manipulation could get rid of the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also use `String.match` and join its result:

```js
const text = 'LTE CSSR (East xr) (301-LT_King_St_PC)';
const cleaned = text.match(/\(.+[^\)]\)/).join(` `);
console.log(cleaned);
```