# Regex extract string between 2 curly braces

Tags: php, regex

I have the following short codes:

> Dear `{{name}}`,
>
> You are being invited for the following event: `{{event}}`
>
> regards, `{{author}}`

I have an array from the database :
`$data`

where:

```
$data['name'] = 'John Doe';
$data['event'] = 'Party yay!';
$data['author'] = 'Kehke Lunga';
```

Output that I expect:

> Dear John Doe,
>
> You are being invited for the following event: Party yay!
>
> regards, Kehke Lunga

also, I also want to perform operations like `{{firstname||lastname}}` which should either check if key `$data['firstname']` is set, if it isn't it should use `$data['lastname']`. However, that is for later stage.

For now, I just want to know how to match the text between 2 curly braces.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And for the second operations you need it could be something this way:

```
$str = "Dear {{name||email}}, You are being invited for the following event: {{event}}. Regards, {{author}}";

// $data['name'] = 'John Doe'; 
$data['email'] = 'JohnDoe@unknown.com'; 
$data['event'] = 'Party yay!'; 
$data['author'] = 'Kehke Lunga';

$pattern = '/{{(.*?)[\|\|.*?]?}}/';

$replace = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($match) use ($data)
{
    $match = explode('||',$match[1]);

    return isset($data[$match[0]]) ? $data[$match[0]] : $data[$match[1]] ;
}, $str);

echo $replace;
```

Basically by editing the '$pattern', and then find the correct logic needed inside the callback.

Answer (score 4):

With [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$pattern = '~\{\{(.*?)\}\}~';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/function.preg-replace-callback):

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'event' => 'Party yay!',
    'author' => 'Kehke Lunga',
);

$str = 'Dear {{name}},
You are being invited for the following event: {{event}}
regards, {{author}}';

$str = preg_replace_callback('/{{(\w+)}}/', function($match) use($data) {
    return $data[$match[1]];
}, $str );

echo($str);
```

output:

```
Dear John Doe,
    You are being invited for the following event: Party yay!
    regards, Kehke Lunga
```

Comment: Looks like this fits more the OP's needs. I have to admit that I just read the headline of the question :) ...

Answer (score 2):

Use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) to match the text between 2 curly braces :

```
$subject = "{{Lorem}}";
$pattern = '/\{\{([^}]+)\}\}/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Take a look at similar [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413071/regex-to-get-string-between-curly-braces-i-want-whats-between-the-curly-brace?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

```
$matches = array();
$a="{{name}}";
preg_match('/\{(.+)\{(.+)\}\}/', $a, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```