# Extracting all values between curly braces regex php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have content in this form

```
$content ="<p>This is a sample text where {123456} and {7894560} ['These are samples']{145789}</p>";
```

I need all the values between curly braces in an array like the one shown below:

```
array("0"=>"123456","1"=>"7894560","2"=>"145789")
```

I tried with this code:

```
<?php
preg_match_all("/\{.*}\/s", $content, $matches);
?>
```

But I am getting in here values from first curly brace to the last found in the content. What can be done to get the array in above format? I knew that the pattern I have used is wrong. What shall be given to get desired output shown above?

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20582312/1578604). The only difference could be that you have 1 brace instead of 2, but the principle remains the same. The main issue is that `.*` is greedy. Almost all the answers on that question tackle that issue.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Do like this...

```
<?php
$content ="<p>This is a sample text where {123456} and {7894560} ['These are samples']{145789}</p>";
preg_match_all('/{(.*?)}/', $content, $matches);
print_r(array_map('intval',$matches[1]));
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123456
    [1] => 7894560
    [2] => 145789
)
```

Answer (score 23):

Two compact solutions weren't mentioned:

```
(?<={)[^}]*(?=})
```

and

```
{\K[^}]*(?=})
```

These allow you to access the matches directly, without capture groups. For instance:

```
$regex = '/{\K[^}]*(?=})/m';
preg_match_all($regex, $yourstring, $matches);
// See all matches
print_r($matches[0]);
```

**Explanation**

- The `(?<={)` lookbehind asserts that what precedes is an opening brace.
- In option 2, `{` matches the opening brace, then `\K` tells the engine to abandon what was matched so far. `\K` is available in Perl, PHP and R (which use the `PCRE` engine), and Ruby 2.0+
- The `[^}]` negated character class represents one character that is not a closing brace,
- and the `*` quantifier matches that zero or more times
- The lookahead `(?=})` asserts that what follows is a closing brace.

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: +1 for both alternatives! Especially for the `\K` version. Never heard it before..

Comment: So is this more performant that the accepted answer? If yes, it would be worth mentioning it.

Answer (score 4):

DEMO :https://eval.in/84197

```
$content ="<p>This is a sample text where {123456} and {7894560} ['These are samples']{145789}</p>";
preg_match_all('/{(.*?)}/', $content, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $a ){
echo $a." ";
}
```

**Output:**

```
123456 7894560 145789
```