# Regex for string enclosed in Brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

After a series of searching, maybe it's time for some help.
How can i write a (PHP) regex to extract the string inside brackets:

```
This is a string with some {{variable1}}, {{variable2}}, and {{variable3}} inside.
```

Output:

```
variable1 or {{variable1}}
variable2 or {{variable2}}
variable3 or {{variable3}}
```

As long as we can extract the variables.

Thank you and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @zx81 why can't you post it on the older question?

Comment: @I3arnon Posted [new answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24443390/1078583). Thanks for the suggestion, that hadn't arisen to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is (probably) that brackets "mean" something in regexes. So you need to escape them, either with `\` (which needs to be doubled) or by putting them in classes `[]`.

```
/\\{\\{([^}]+)\\}\\}/g
```

should do the trick, I believe.