# Regular Expression in Python to match multiple incidents of a string between two known strings

Tags: python, regex, string

In the following text

```
My cow always gives milk. Your cow sometimes produces milk.
```

I want to extract

```
'always gives', 'sometimes produces'
```

Using the encapsulating strings "cow" and "milk".

I tried "cow(.*)milk" following [Regular Expression to get a string between two strings in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642315/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-two-strings-in-javascript) however it only works if the first sentence is alone

```
My cow always gives milk.
```

In my case, using that regular expression returns

```
always gives milk. Your cow sometimes produces
```

Additionally, I have also tried "(?<=foo)[^bar]*(?=bar)" from [Extracting all values between curly braces regex php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838624/extracting-all-values-between-curly-braces-regex-php). And this works great. For example (and this is closer to the actual problem I'm trying to solve)

```
fooSTRINGbar fooCHARACTERSbar
```

Returns

```
'STRING', 'CHARACTERS'
```

Great! But for some reason if "STRING" contains a character that "bar" has, then the match fails. For example,

```
fooSTRaINGbar
```

Doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the non-greedy option:

```
cow(.*?)milk
```

The `?` qualifier tells the regex engine to stop a match at the *earliest* opportunity, rather than greedily trying to match as much as possible (which is the problem you saw with `cow(.*)milk`).

Comment: Alright, this is good. But is there a way I can make it so that if there is a space between the two encapsulating strings, it will ignore the match?. For example, "fooSTRINGbar fooCHAR ACTERSbar" returns only STRING?

Comment: You could use `[^ ]` in place of `.`. (If you specify all your constraints ahead of time you'll get more useful answers!)

Comment: Awesome! Yeah that last little constraint must've slipped my mind. Thanks.

Comment: @Sal `\S` might be better than `[^ ]`. More direct, shorter, and the only difference is that `[^ ]` does match other whitespace, which I can't imagine you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [lookbehind and lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) as anchors between a [non-greedy match](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) as well:

```
>>> s='My cow always gives milk. Your cow sometimes produces milk.'
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\bcow\b)(.*?)(?=\bmilk\b)', s)
[' always gives ', ' sometimes produces ']
```

If you want to strip the surrounding spaces:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\bcow\b)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=\bmilk\b)', s)
['always gives', 'sometimes produces']
```

You can also use a lookahead to validate that the match does not contain spaces:

```
>>> s='My cow gives milk. Your cow sometimes produces milk.'
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\bcow\b)(?=\s*\S+\s*milk\b)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=\bmilk\b)', s)
['gives']
```

Or:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\bcow\b)\s*(\S+)\s*(?=\bmilk\b)', s)
['gives']
```

Same method works with your second example:

```
>>> s='fooSTRINGbar fooCHARACTERSbar'
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=foo)([A-Z]+)(?=bar)', s)
['STRING', 'CHARACTERS']
```