# how to get the array of strings that are inside curly braces in the source string in java

Tags: java, regex

There is a string object in java with its contents as:

```
String sourceString="This {is} a sample {string} that {contains} {substrings} inside curly {braces}";
```

I want the array of string with its contents as: `{is},{string},{contains},{substrings}{braces}`

Following is the code that I wrote to get the result but the output I am getting is:

```
"{is} a sample {string} that {contains} {substrings} inside curly {braces}"
```

So, basically it is taking all the characters that are in between the first open curly braces and last closing curly braces.

```
// Source string
String sourceString="This {is} a samle {string} that {contains} {substrings} inside curly {braces}";

// Regular expression to get the values between curly braces (there is a mistake, I guess)
String regex="\\{(.*)\\}";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(sourceString);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you attempted the problem yet? If yes,please show us your code. If not, then we would suggest you to try this on your own first, and then wherever you're stuck, we would be happy to help.

Comment: Do you want to keep the braces?

Comment: @Bohemian: OP said: *I want the array of string with its contents as: {is},{string},{contains},{substrings}{braces}*.

Comment: Hey @Bohemian. Hope to see that diamond besides your name soon :)

Comment: @RohitJain: I too made a tick up for [Bohemian](http://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian). :)

Comment: @RohitJain I hope to see your name in next year's election! And thanks guys! I appreciate the good wishes :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little bit of Googling found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413071/regex-to-get-string-between-curly-braces-i-want-whats-between-the-curly-brace) solution, which gave me ideas for the pattern

Some time spent with [Lesson: Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) brought the libraries and functionality I would need to provide this example...

```
String exp = "\\{(.*?)\\}";

String value = "This {is} a samle {string} that {contains} {substrings} inside curly {braces}";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(exp);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);

List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>(5);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String group = matcher.group();
    matches.add(group);
}

String[] groups = matches.toArray(new String[matches.size()]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(groups));
```

Which outputs

```
[{is}, {string}, {contains}, {substrings}, {braces}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the one line solution:

```
String[] resultArray = str.replaceAll("^[^{]*|[^}]*$", "").split("(?<=\\})[^{]*");
```

This works by first stripping off the leading and trailing junk, then splitting on everything between `}` and `{`.

---

Here's some test code:

```
String str = "This {is} a samle {string} that {contains} {substrings} inside curly";
String[] resultArray = str.replaceAll("^[^{]*|[^}]*$", "").split("(?<=\\})[^{]*");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultArray));
```

Output:

```
[{is}, {string}, {contains}, {substrings}]
```

Answer (score 0):

- Pattern which will match `{characters}` can look like `\\{[^}]*\\}`.
- Now using `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes you can find each substring that matches this regex.
- Place each of founded substring in `List<String>`
- After list is filled with all substrings you can convert it to array using `yourList.toArray(newStringArray)` method.

---

EDIT after your update

Problem with your regex is that `*` quantifier is greedy which means it will try to find maximal possible solution. So in case of `\\{(.*)\\}` it will match

- first possible `{`,
- zero or more characters
- last possible `}` which in case of

  ```
  This {is} a samle {string} that {contains} {substrings} inside curly {braces}
  ```

means it will start from `{` in `{is}` and finis in `}` from `{braces}`

To make `*` find minimal set of characters which can be used to create matching substring you need to either

- add `?` after it making `*?` quantifier reluctant,
- describe your regex as I did originally and exclude `}` from possible match between `{` and `}`, so instead of matching any characters which represents `.` use `[^}]` which represents any character except `}`.

Comment: If you have trouble with some part of this solution feel free to ask more specific question.