# Get all strings that match a pattern in JQuery/Javascript or regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm terrible at regular expression and need help with getting all strings that starts with `[` and end with `]` within a string.

```
Example: "This is the match [*more*] or [*less*]" 

And I want to get [*more*], [*less*] into an array
```

I have tried something like this but it's not correct: `/\[\*([^}]+)\*\]/g`

Comment: add "more" and "less" OR "[*more*]" and "[*less*]" ? or is that a formatting error?

Comment: I found something that gives me an idea how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21845294/how-to-get-the-array-of-strings-that-are-inside-curly-braces-in-the-source-strin

Comment: @sunbabaphu: it should be "[more]" and "[less]"

Comment: This should give me all the matches: sourceString.match(/\[.*?\]/g);

Comment: pretty much.. it might need *escaping*

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var str = "This is the match [more] or [less]";
var you_arr = str.match(/(\[.*?\])/g);
```

resultant `your_arr`: `("[more]","[less]")`