# How can I convert string to a array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following array:

```
var mystr = "Name[Daniel],Name2[Alguien],Date[2009],Date[2014]";
```

How can I convert it to an array like this:

```
var array = ['Daniel','Alguien','2009',2014];
```

Comment: Split it into an array by `split("-")` and then regex out the value with regex

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Duplicate of [*Regex to get string between curly braces “{I want what's between the curly braces}”*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413071/regex-to-get-string-between-curly-braces-i-want-whats-between-the-curly-brace)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
var mystr = "Name[Daniel],Name2[Alguien],Date[2009],Date[2014]"; 
var array = mystr.match(/\[.+?\]/g).map(function(value){  // searches for values in []
    return value.replace(/[\[\]]/g,""); // removes []
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Your first piece of code works perfectly. The new solution doesn´t seem to work, **Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/wx4Lm/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code , as you can see the string is split by comma and then using regular expressions the necessary part has been pushed to new array

```
var mystr = "Name[Daniel],Name2[Alguien],Date[2009],Date[2014]";
var array = mystr.split(",");
re = /\[(.*)\]/;
var newArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newArray.push(array[i].match(re)[1]);
}

newArray = ['Daniel', 'Alguien', '2009', 2014];
```