# Regular expression for parsing out CSS rules block

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Has snippet of CSS:

```
.__chat.__32x32 {
    color: white;
    background: url({ANYNAME:anyName}Images/icons/32x32/chat.png{ANYNAME}) no-repeat;
}
```

The problem: need to parse out block of css(selector+rules block). Bu closing curly bracket in url considered by my pattern as closing for rules block. All the tries with lookarounds at this point did not give me a success.
Question: How to make pattern consider construction {anyname} as part of the match string if it is inside url: rule or rules block?

```
var parser = new Regex(@"([a-z0-9\s,*\""\[\]=\.\:#_\-@]+){((?>[^}]+|(?:(?<={ROOT)|(?<={VERSION))})*)}|(\/\*(?:(?:(?!\*\/)[\S\s])+)\*\/)", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            MatchCollection matches;

            matches = parser.Matches(fullContent);

            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                if (match.Value.IndexOf("/*") > -1)
                {
                    var cssComment = new CssComment(match.Value);
                    _cssElements.Add(cssComment);
                }
                else
                {
                    var cssBlock = new CssBlock(match.Groups[1].Value.Trim(), match.Groups[2].Value.Trim());
                    _cssElements.Add(cssBlock);
                }
            }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to get string between curly braces "{I want what's between the curly braces}"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413071/regex-to-get-string-between-curly-braces-i-want-whats-between-the-curly-brace)

Comment: What language/tool are you using? You have a nested structure. You will either need balancing groups (.net) or a recursive regex (pcre/perl). Also, at least show what you have tried...

Comment: C# and for testing the pattern the http://regex101.com/r/tU2zB3/1

Comment: @setty regex101 uses pcre and you're using C#. This means you're using a tester that doesn't support balancing groups. I suggest you to test your regexes on http://regexhero.net and check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003799/what-are-regular-expression-balancing-groups/17004406#17004406) out

Comment: @setty you didn't show any code. So how am I supposed to know the problem you're encountering?

Comment: @HamZa the problem is not in the code itself, until the {ANYNAME} placeholder has been added code worked correct, now the main problem is pattern, it did not parse out blocks correctly

Comment: @setty again show the regex/code you're using.

Comment: @HamZa actually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003799/what-are-regular-expression-balancing-groups/17004406#17004406 helped. I found http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28?%3a%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%7C%28?%3COpen%3E%7B%29%7C%28?%3CContent-Open%3E%7D%29%29%2b%28?%28Open%29%28?!%29%29&i=0%20%7B1%202%20%7B3%7D%20%7B4%205%20%7B6%7D%7D%207%7D%208 case which is very similar to my but still it is too fancy

Comment: Adds to many unneded groups

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
[.#]?[\w\s.<>]+{(\n.*)+?(?=\n}\n)\n}
```

it matches whole block (selector+inside code). You may have to make some alterations in the selector part `[.#]?[\w\s.<>]`  to make it work for your problem.