# Pattern match to get string between brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find whatever string is in between the aggregate() and find(). Below is my code.

```
var str1 = 'aggregate([{$group:{_id:{state:"$state",city:"$city"},sum:{$sum:"$pop"}}},{$sort:{sum:1}},{$group:{_id:"$_id.state",smallestcity:{$first:"$_id.city"},smallest:{$first:"$sum"},largestcity:{$last:"$_id.city"},largest:{$last:"$sum"}}}])'
var str2 = 'find({awards:{$elemMatch:{award:"Turing Award",year:{$gt:1980}}}}).limit(0)'

var matchPharse = /((.*))/;
var result = str1.match(matchPharse);
console.log(result);
```

I am getting the result always the whole string instead of

```
[{$group:{_id:{state:"$state",city:"$city"},sum:{$sum:"$pop"}}},{$sort:{sum:1}},{$group:{_id:"$_id.state",smallestcity:{$first:"$_id.city"},smallest:{$first:"$sum"},largestcity:{$last:"$_id.city"},largest:{$last:"$sum"}}}]
```

[I am searching for something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413071/regex-to-get-string-between-curly-braces-i-want-whats-between-the-curly-brace#)

Comment: @AvinashRaj I think OP posted the expected output after "instead of"

Answer (score 1):

try this pattern instead:

```
var matchPharse = /((\[.*\]))/;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
((\[.*?\]))
```

You Should use a `non greedy` expression.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following RegEx:

```
var matchPharse= /\((.*)\)/g;
```

Matches any sequence between `()`.

This is a [**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/eP5sT7/1).

```js
var str1 = 'aggregate([{$group:{_id:{state:"$state",city:"$city"},sum:{$sum:"$pop"}}},{$sort:{sum:1}},{$group:{_id:"$_id.state",smallestcity:{$first:"$_id.city"},smallest:{$first:"$sum"},largestcity:{$last:"$_id.city"},largest:{$last:"$sum"}}}])'
var str2 = 'find({awards:{$elemMatch:{award:"Turing Award",year:{$gt:1980}}}}).limit(0)'
var matchPharse = /\((.*)\)/;
var result = str1.match(matchPharse);
alert(result);
```

Comment: Please correct me if I am doing something wrong in the below split. Im splitting on },
var str = '{"a": 2000, "b": "sam"},{"c":1,"d":1}'
var res = str.split(/(?:\}\,|\,\{)/);
console.log(res[0]) //'{"a": 2000, "b": "sam"' - One bracket is missing
console.log(res[1]) //'{"c":1,"d":1}'

Expecting output
res[0] = {"a": 2000, "b": "sam"}

Comment: if you use split() on } the `}` will not count in the splitted strings.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape the outside parentheses. Try:

```
var matchPharse = /\((.*)\)/;
```

For just the content inside the parentheses use `result[1]`

Comment: that would include the parentheses