# Regex to match content inside @{...} construct with bracket balancing

Tags: php, regex

I want to create a regular expression that captures text between `@{ some text }`. I know how to do it for simple string, but in this case the text between the `@{` `}` might contain starting and ending curly braces which will be confused with the braces in `@{` `}`.

Example:

**Input string:**

```
This is some text that does not match the regex

@{

    This is some text

    {
        This another text

        {
            inner text
        }
    }

}

@{
    this is text2
}

another text that does not match the regex


@{
    this is another text
    {
        another inner text
    }
}
```

**The result (3 matches) should be:**

First match:

```
This is some text

{
    This another text

    {
        inner text
    }
}
```

Second match:

```
this is text2
```

Third match:

```
this is another text
{
    another inner text
}
```

Can anybody tell me how to achieve this? I'm using PHP by the way.

Comment: With a subroutine call.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: There are a lot of questions about how to match nested brackets with a regex in php. A little search will give you the answer.

Comment: You can read about subroutine calls [here](http://regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to get string between curly braces "{I want what's between the curly braces}"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413071/regex-to-get-string-between-curly-braces-i-want-whats-between-the-curly-brace)

Comment: @l'L'l this is not what I'm looking for, I updated my examples to describe what I want.

Comment: Wanting something and trying something are two different things, I recommend the latter since this isn't a "code my stuff for free" site.

Comment: @l'L'l: I disagree with the duplicate target, since the question you suggest doesn't have a proper solution for arbitrarily nested brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably need a [recursive regex](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html) to solve the nested braces:

```
if(preg_match_all('/@(?={)([^}{]+|{((?1)*)})/', $str, $out)!==false)
  print_r($out[2]);
```

- `@(?={)` starts at `@` [if followed by](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) an opening brace
- `[^}{]` matches any character [that is not](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) a brace
- At `(?1)` is pasted from first parenthesized subpattern
- `((?1)*)` captures wanted stuff to second group

See [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pF1uN2/3), [test at eval.in](https://eval.in/420981), [SO regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) if interested :]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I'm trying to accomplish :)

Comment: Hi, I have a similar question and tried to modify your answer to work in my situation but can't get it working. Would you mind taking a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33218671/recursive-handling-of-nested-curly-braces-with-regex-for-cms

Comment: @DanL - If you _undelete_ that question, I can post an answer for you.