# Split a string with '[' and ']'

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I would like to know the RegEx Split pattern (using C#) for a string which packed with `[` and `]`.

For example, for the string:

```
This is my [word1] And this is my [word2]
```

I should get `word1` and `word2`.

Comment: better look into this one https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `/[(.*?)]/` .. You can find detail **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/413077/2065039)**

Comment: use RegEx Matches instead of RegEx Split?

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
\[(?<word>[^\]]*)\]
```

I would suggest you use some regex tool to assist you.  I'm sure there are a couple but I use [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) and it really helps with these pesky things :)

Answer (score 0):

Use regex `/\[(.*?)\]/g`. Given regex is in perl, similar is in other langauges too. Worked out here: 
https://regex101.com/r/zL0yW1/1