# split JSON and string in android

Tags: java, json

My HTTP Request responds with combination of string and JSON, something like this:

> null{"username:name","email:email"}

I need only the JSON part.

I directly tried parsing as json object, which was not right of course. I tried splitting it: `serverResponse.split("{")`, but android does not allow to parse with this character because it is not a pattern. Any suggestion how i can achieve this?

Comment: You can try something similar to these.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413071/regex-to-get-string-between-curly-braces-i-want-whats-between-the-curly-brace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String.split` uses regular expressions, and since `'{'` is a special character in regular expressions, you should escape it like this: `serverResponse.split("\\{")`.

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to change the server side, but you can also just use split. The only thing you need to do is escape your `{`.

```
String json = serverResponse.split("\\{")[1];
```

Comment: I also don't know why the server side sends null because it is not handled by me. I just had to get json and parse it. Thank you for the helpful reply.

Comment: Probably the server sends JSONP, which is used for javascript, the null is actually the `callback` variable. Try to get the url like: `http:yoururl.com/?callback=` to see if that gives you an empty string in front.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea and a bad practice to `split` a `Json`. If one day it you change on the serve side, it may pick a wrong part of your `Json Object`. 
I recommend you to `PARSE` it, even if it is simple and small.

Comment: He does not want to split the json, he wants to remove the null in front.

Comment: Yes i wanted to separate the "null" and the json object which i succeed by serverResponse.split("\\{").