# regex to retrieve specific url from text

Tags: javascript, regex, match

An API I use returns this text:

```
<http://192.168.1.10:8080/longUrl>; rel="recording-session",
<http://192.168.1.10:8080/realLongUrl>; rel="h264-session-sdp", 
<http://192.168.1.10:8080/realLongDifferentUrl>; rel="h264-session-sdp", 
<rtp://239.1.1.18:5006>; rel="destination-high", 
<rtp://239.1.1.17:5006>; rel="destination-low"
```

I'm trying to retrieve the first URL that is followed by `; rel="h264-session-sdp`.

So in this case that would be: `http://192.168.1.10:8080/realLongUrl`

I've been fiddling around trying to modify examples found here on SO, but just can's seem to get it right.

Comment: Can you show some of the fiddled regex that didn't work.

Comment: Mainly been trying to modify the regex example found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/413165/1577926. Replacing the curly brackets with my own delimiters. I keep getting the delimiters in the match as well as the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one `/([^<]+)(?:>; rel\=\"h264\-session\-sdp\")/`

Comment: I belive the OP wants it to be reusable for multiple API calls, so that it would also work for `<rtp://239.1.1.17:5006>; rel="destination-low"`, etc

Comment: this will return only FIRST mutch

Answer (score 0):

Selects the text inbetween the greater then and less then characters:

> ?<=\<)(.*?)(?=>)
>
> https://regex101.com/r/oS5sX6/1

And if you wanted to select the urls on multiple lines, add the g and m modifiers:

> /(?<=\<)(.*?)(?=>)/gm
>
> https://regex101.com/r/oS5sX6/2

Comment: Tried to modify it to only the one I need, but it says it's invalid....

SyntaxError: invalid regexp group
`var res = linkHeaders.match( /(?<=\<)(.*?)(?=\>)>; rel=\"h264-session-sdp\"/ );`

Comment: try `var res = linkHeaders.match( /(?<=\<)(.*?)(?=\>)>; rel=\"h264-session-sdp\");` note the removed ending slash

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/(?<=\<)(.*?)(?=\>)>; rel="h264-session-sdp"/
```