# Regex replace specific words in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like "Please .... {@@url} something{@@test}somethinng ... some{@@url} ....", would like to replace exactly the strings {@@url} and {@@test} through regex in c#

Kindly help me to get the regex pattern

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Regex to get string between curly braces "{I want what's between the curly braces}"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413071/regex-to-get-string-between-curly-braces-i-want-whats-between-the-curly-brace)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx

So something like

```
string pattern = @"/{(.*?)}/";
string input = "Please .... {@@url} something{@@test}somethinng ... some{@@url} ....";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1} matches):", input, matches.Count);
  foreach (Match match in matches)
     input = input.replace(match.value, "");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stewart for refrences