# "Cut out" a specific Text of a file and put it into a string

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, file

My application saves informations into a file like this:

```
[Name]{ExampleName}
[Path]{ExamplePath}
[Author]{ExampleAuthor}
```

I want to cut the [Name]{....} out and just get back the "ExampleName".

```
//This is what the strings should contain in the end.
string name = "ExampleName"
string path = "ExamplePath"
```

Is there any way to do this in C#?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413071/regex-to-get-string-between-curly-braces-i-want-whats-between-the-curly-brace and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets .

Comment: Of course there's a way to do this in C#. Did you try anything regarding this problem you have? Please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you want to store structured data, why not to use the standard mechanisms like JSON serialization or XML serialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the keys and the values and push them into a dictionary that you can later easily access like this:

```
var text = "[Name]{ExampleName} [Path]{ExamplePath} [Author]{ExampleAuthor}";

// You can use regex to extract the Value/Pair
var rgx = new Regex(@"\[(?<key>[a-zA-Z]+)\]{(?<value>[a-zA-Z]+)}", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
var matches = rgx.Matches(text);

// Now you can add the values to a dictionary
var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    dic.Add(match.Groups["key"].Value, match.Groups["value"].Value);
}

// Then you can access your values like this.
var name = dic["Name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to cut out the string part between brackets:

```
var regex = new Regex("\[.*\]{(?<variableName>.*)}");
```

If you try matching this regular expression on your strings, you end up with your resulting strings in the match group 'variableName' (`match.Groups["variableName"].Value`).

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure to understand what you need but I will try.

You can use this :

```
var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("Name"));
var newText = regex.Replace("NameExampleName", "", 1);
```

Comment: OP is asking for two strings; `name` and `path`. How are those created from your example?

Comment: Also, OP is not asking about how to replace text. So why are you calling `regex.Replace`?