# Using a regex expression to parse information between brackets

Tags: regex

I am trying to parse information with regex, that is laid out in a style similar to json. Part of the problem I am having doing this involved identifying pairs of curly brackets.

```
group = {
    field = element
    innergroup = {
        field = element
        field = element
    }
    field = element
    innergroup = { field = element }
}

array = { field = element }
```

The first step in solving this problem is to identify the inner groups, bracketed off material that has no curly brackets between them. In the above example:

```
innergroup = {
    field = element
    field = element
}
#and
innergroup = { field = element }
#and
array = { field = element }
```

I have tried to find these inner groups by using a few different regex commands. This is the closest I got.

```
\{.*?\}
```

I know that it has something to do with the fact that the "." character means all characters except for line breaks. I also have to figure out a way to rule out characters that are either of the curly brackets.

[Update]

Previous questions have asked how to do this when the curly brackets are all on one line. However, this does not address this innergroup.

```
innergroup = {
    field = element
    field = element
}
```

The other questions also don't take into account the fact that there are many curly brackets, and thus other regex functions will find things like.

```
group = {
    field = element
    innergroup = {
        field = element
        field = element
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try DOTALL flag: `(?s)\{.*?\}`

Comment: The [answer is already available here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44708840/3832970).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a negative character class:

```
\{[^{}]*?\}
```

`[^{}]` means “any character except a curly bracket” (escapes are not necessary).

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/CfdkFnP6Ps).