# regex - find the value between quotes for a particular key

Tags: regex

From a string, I have to find the 'value' for a particular key(variable)
to find a regex pattern to find the value between the quotes.

```
keyx:'value1',keyn:'value2', keys....
```

like for keyn - the regex must return value2

It is not a json format. This string is extracted from an XML tag.

I have tried this regex (["'])(?:(?=(\?))\2.)*?\1
and trying to modify it to make it work for my scenario

Comment: How about: `(?<=keyx:')[^']+(?=')` ? ... assuming that the values would always be surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: What language are you using this in? If you split string by "," , then you could use something `'.+'` to match on each of the split bits

Comment: @Rashmirathi What if some of the values have commas inside them?

Comment: @Rashmirathi java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to get string between curly braces "{I want what's between the curly braces}"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413071/regex-to-get-string-between-curly-braces-i-want-whats-between-the-curly-brace)

Comment: @PoulBak the one that you marked duplicate is a different scenario. I think you cant understand the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex to your values:

```
key\w:'(.*?)'[, ]*?
```

You need to set the `global` flag.

The regex starts by mathing `'key'` followed by a `Word char`, `colon` and a single `quote`, then creates a capture Group of everything between the single quotes, followed by a single `quote`, and zero or more `commas` and `Spaces`.

You get your value from Group 1.
That will produce `'value1'` and `'value2'`.