# How to extract text from another text?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

`group:[random text]_updated_at`

and I'm trying to extract the text inside the brackets []. Basically I want to print out this text:

```
random text
```

I've tried using split function

```
let arr = str.split('[')[1];

console.log(arr); // random text]_updated_at
```

but I believe it could better using regex? Does anyone know how I can print the text using regex?

**NOTE:**

1. I don't want to use **substring** because the text within the brackets could potentially change.
2. The text **group:** will always be there in the beginning.

Comment: Have a look at this community wiki [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) which explains common regex tasks (which this is) and also links to an answer which provides a regex for [text in between curly brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413071/regex-to-get-string-between-curly-braces/413077#413077) which you should easily be able to adjust to work for square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think **match** function might be right fit for the job. For example, check the code below:

```
let str = "group:[random text]_updated_at";
let match = str.match(/group:\[(.*?)\]/);
if (match) {
  console.log(match[1]); // Output: "random text"
}
```

Comment: str.match(/group:\[(.*?)\]_(\w+)/) should work in case if updated_at is needed to be kept. match[1] + " " + match[2] could be used to calculate the final output.